# Prevent runaway threads and ultimately physical overheating and battery drain on Android

Tags: battery, battery-life

I was wondering if there is a system monitor app that will raise (audible) alerts and offer app closure if it detects runaway threads on Android that cause physical overheating and battery drain.

E.g., I just had to turn my phone off because there was a runaway thread that I think was constantly trying to refresh FB where there was very poor connection, so it was going in a virtually endless loop.  But I get that with other apps too and not just Facebook.

I'd like to actually shut apps down when they're detected.

I am not kidding, I nearly burned my fingertips when I touched my phone -- it was on for only 2 hrs and the battery was almost dead.  It is because 4G is very poor inside my office building and I checked Facebook walking between my vehicle and the building this AM.  After that, the app kept trying to refresh continuously without success and overheating the phone.

Comment: Apps may drain your battery, but they should never cause a device to overheat. If you experience overheating there might be a different, physical defect with the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment, "battery drain" and "overheating" are not necessarily connected: not everything that drains your battery causes overheating. Overheating is most likely caused by excessive CPU hogging (which of course also leads to battery drain).

You might want to take a look at the app [DrainGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waldafx.DrainGuard), which keeps a log of battery consumption, always informs you how much was consumed since you turned the screen off last time, and -- here it comes -- it can start an alarm when some app causes excessive battery drain. Values are configurable:

[image: DrainGuard Alarm Config] [image: Drainguard Alarm]

The free version only works from 100% charge down to 70%, which is fine for testing. Once you decided the app serves your purpose, the [DrainGuard PRO Key](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.waldafx.DrainGuardProKey) is available on the playstore for less than an Euro.